# Remove PHP extension from the url BING search results

Tags: .htaccess

I have .htaccess code which removes .php extension from the url.
This code works fine and I don't see .php at the end of the url,
in the google search results.
I started Bing webmaster tools few days ago. Bing crawled my urls and there are php extensions in the Bing's results. Do I need to modify my code?

Thanks

Here is the code

```
## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the R (Temp Redirect) to R=301 (Permanent Redirect) to permanently redirect "foo.php" to "/foo".

```
## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

R=301 tells the search engines to update their databases with the new url.